# Showing function is a diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\mathbb{S_1}$ and $\mathbb{S_2}$ be two regular surfaces with a mapping $f:\mathbb{S_1}\to \mathbb{S_2}$ which I have shown to be bijective from $\mathbb{S_1}$ to $\mathbb{S_2}$. From the definition of a diffeomorphism, I also have to show that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are differentiable.

To do this, I parameterize a subset of $\mathbb{S_1}$ by $x_1(u_1,v_1)$ and the corresponding subset of $\mathbb{S_2}$ by $y_1(u_2,v_2)$ and show that both $y_1^{-1}\circ f\circ x_1$ and its inverse are differentiable. Then I do the same again but with other parameterizations $x_2$ and $y_2$ such that $x_2$ covers the part of $\mathbb{S_1}$ which $x_1$ didn't cover (and $y_2$ parameterizes the corresponding patch of $\mathbb{S_2}$ mapped to by $f\circ x_2$).

Is this a correct procedure for showing that $f:\mathbb{S_1}\to \mathbb{S_2}$ is a differomorphism?

Comment: Yes, this way is correct. Note that in some cases there are other, simpler ways to show that a map is a diffeomorphism. Depends on the specific surfaces and map. However, if you follow the steps written in your post, and you make sure that the surfaces are covered by the parametrizations you handle, then you will have shown what you want to.